# How to access the data in printarea of excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My worksheet have 5 pages to print. I got total no of print pages from print area and now i want to access only page 2 as have to change data in it.
Kindly support as i am struggling and haven't find any answerer of it.
example of code is given below

```
dim count,a as integer
count=sheet3.pagesetup.pages.count
for a=1 to count
' a will go into every page
 if a=2 then
  msgbox "its page 2"
end if
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the comma separated address strings, representing the range addresses of the pages, returned by accessing the `PrintArea` property of the [`PageSetUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea) object. Index into the resultant array to get the address string to use with `Range` to interact with data in a specific page.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr() As String, pages As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    pages = ws.PageSetup.pages.Count
    
    arr = Split(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea, ",")
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To ws.PageSetup.pages.Count
        Debug.Print ws.Range(arr(i - 1)).Address
    Next

End Sub
```